# Create an SQL Server dataset with Power BI pro

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have create an account on app.powerbi.com

I want to link a dataset to an external sql server database.

I have only 4 choices:

- Azure SQL Database
- Azure SQL Data WareHouse
- SQL Server Analysis Services
- Spark on Azure HDInsights

It is not possible to choose SQL Server Database. I want to type a connexionstring...

Is it a powerbi online limitation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe Power BI online have some limitations, I have no problem using SQL Server in Power BI desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI online has a limited number of data connection types, in those instances listed, they are Azure services that you can directly link to.

For self hosted SQL Server instances, you use Power BI Desktop to connect to the database, create the report and load it to the service.

You will need a Power BI Data Gateway to connect to service to the SQL Server. If you have a Gateway you can use Power BI Dataflows to connect to the database via the Gateway, then link Power BI to them.

Comment: What do you mean by "Power BI Data Gateway" ? How can i create this gateway ? Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem